# Erro Datatable Server-Side ( Invalid JSON response ) - PHP

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, jquery-datatables, datatable

Boa tarde galera da comunidade! estou quebrando a cabeça um pouco, tentando utilizar `Datatable Server-Side` para solucionar o meu problema, primeira vez que estou tendo contato com a mesma.

Vou estar deixando o meu código abaixo, e já digo os problemas...

**Script:**

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('#tabela_server').DataTable({
      'processing': true,
      'serverSide': true,
      'serverMethod': 'post',
      'ajax': {
          'url':'../server.php'
      },
      'columns': [
         { data: 'nome' },
         { data: 'data_de_entrada' },
         { data: 'data_de_nascimento' },
         { data: 'convenio' },
         { data: 'data_saida' },
      ]
   });
});
</script>
```

**server.php:**

```
<?php
$server = "exemplo";
$username = "exemplo";
$password = "exemplo";
$dbname = "exemplo";
// Criando a conexão
try{
   $con = new PDO("mysql:host=$server;dbname=$dbname","$username","$password");
   $con->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE,PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
}catch(PDOException $e){
   die('Não foi possível conectar-se ao banco de dados');
}

## Ler valores
$draw = $_POST['draw'];
$row = $_POST['start'];
$rowperpage = $_POST['length']; // Linhas exibidas por página
$columnIndex = $_POST['order'][0]['column']; // Index da coluna
$columnName = $_POST['columns'][$columnIndex]['data']; // Nome da coluna
$columnSortOrder = $_POST['order'][0]['dir']; // asc ou desc
$searchValue = $_POST['search']['value']; // Buscar valor

$searchArray = array();

## Buscar 
$searchQuery = " ";
if($searchValue != ''){
   $searchQuery = " AND (nome LIKE :nome or 
        data_de_entrada LIKE :data_de_entrada OR 
        data_de_nascimento LIKE :data_de_nascimento OR
        convenio LIKE :convenio OR
        data_saida LIKE :data_saida) ";
   $searchArray = array( 
        'nome'=>"%$searchValue%", 
        'data_de_entrada'=>"%$searchValue%",
        'data_de_nascimento'=>"%$searchValue%",
        'convenio'=>"%$searchValue%",
        'data_saida'=>"%$searchValue%"
   );
}

## Total de números de registros SEM filtros
$stmt = $con->prepare("SELECT COUNT(*) AS allcount FROM pacientes ");
$stmt->execute();
$records = $stmt->fetch();
$totalRecords = $records['allcount'];

## Total de números de registros COM filtros
$stmt = $con->prepare("SELECT COUNT(*) AS allcount FROM pacientes WHERE 1 ".$searchQuery);
$stmt->execute($searchArray);
$records = $stmt->fetch();
$totalRecordwithFilter = $records['allcount'];

## Buscar registros
$stmt = $con->prepare("SELECT * FROM pacientes WHERE 1 ".$searchQuery." ORDER BY ".$columnName." ".$columnSortOrder." LIMIT :limit,:offset");

// Valores de ligação
foreach($searchArray as $key=>$search){
   $stmt->bindValue(':'.$key, $search,PDO::PARAM_STR);
}

$stmt->bindValue(':limit', (int)$row, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$stmt->bindValue(':offset', (int)$rowperpage, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$stmt->execute();
$empRecords = $stmt->fetchAll();

$data = array();

foreach($empRecords as $row){
   $data[] = array(
      "nome"=>$row['nome'],
      "data_de_entrada"=>$row['data_de_entrada'],
      "data_de_nascimento"=>$row['data_de_nascimento'],
      "convenio"=>$row['convenio'],
      "data_saida"=>$row['data_saida']
   );
}


## Response
$response = array(
   "draw" => intval($draw),
   "iTotalRecords" => $totalRecords,
   "iTotalDisplayRecords" => $totalRecordwithFilter,
   "aaData" => $data
);

echo json_encode($response);
```

**ERRO:** (Somente em algumas páginas...)

> DataTables warning: table id=tabela_server - Invalid JSON response. For more information about this error, please see http://datatables.net/tn/1

*Bom, eu já tentei achar aonde esta o erro, acessando `http://datatables.net/tn/1`, porém não consegui, sou um pouco leigo no assunto, vou estar deixando um print abaixo mostrado o que aparece no navegador, nas paginas que estão com erro...*

[image: PRINT]

**Obs**: Os dados são exibidos normalmente na tabela, só não é exibido algumas páginas que estão com esse erro...

Comment: Alguém me ajuda :(

Comment: O que você está enviando para o servidor? Poste o conteúdo da aba Headers do seu console.

Answer (score -1):

Sei que já faz um tempo desde a ultima atualização dessa duvida, nesse caso em especifico como o amigo já realizou o teste em analisar a pagina no modo desenvolvedor e não obteve nenhum retorno "This request has no response data available" isso significa que o seu script que ficou responsável por coletar os dados do banco nem está conseguindo converter o payload em json.

Por exemplo a maioria dos scripts (PHP) que ficam ao lado do servidor terminam com algo tipo:

```
echo json_encode($response);
exit;
```

Essa é a razão do porque você não tem nenhuma resposta no navegador, não aparece nada pra você porque nem chegou a montar a resposta como JSON.

Geralmente esse tipo de problema acontece porque trabalhando no localhost definimos charset UTF8 /uft8_unicode_ci para o banco que se esta testando e quando consumimos algum banco que já se encontra no servidor o seu padrão pode estar diferente deste do localhost ou vice-versa, a aplicação não vai conseguir converter o retorno da consulta em JSON porque o conteudo dela não esta convertido para UTF8 e então vai dar esse erro - Invalid JSON response

Não precisa alterar o padrão do seu banco caso esteja diferente, bastaria converter para UTF8, no exemplo abaixo não vou me aprofundar na variável $con essa variável seria como se fosse as configurações do seu banco:

```
$query = "select * from TESTE"; 
$runQuery = mysqli_query($con, $query);
$data = array();

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($runQuery)) {

    $data[] = array(
            "NOME" => utf8_encode($row['NOME']),
            "DESCRICAO" => utf8_encode($row['DESCRICAO']),
            "ID" => $row['ID']
        );
}

$response = array(
    "draw" => intval($draw),
    "iTotalRecords" => $totalRecords,
    "iTotalDisplayRecords" => $totalRecordwithFilter,
    "aaData" => $data
);
            
echo json_encode($response);
exit;
```

Essa solução nem sempre é a mais viável, já vi casos onde acessando o modo dev do navegador você consegue ter um retorno mais claro do problema, erros de SQL por exemplo, mais nesse caso o problema era que nem aparecia nada na resposta do console, então é muito provável que nunca chegou a montar nenhuma resposta porque não conseguiu converter os dados em JSON.